# How can I test EJB 3.0?

Tags: unit-testing, jakarta-ee, ejb, integration-testing

I am using EJB 3.0 , Oracle WebLogic.

Need help in the following question :

**How to test EJB (3.0) ?** I mean unit tests and/or integration tests ? Can I use some kind of embedded EJB container or create a mock for it to write unit tests ? Maybe there is some special test frameworks or aproaches? EJB aren't new for me, but I have never written tests for them. 
Any information will be useful for me .

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One option is using embedded container. Starts up on every test execution, you have to get your beans through jndi lookup, manage container's configuration yourself and all kind of boring, unproductive stuff.

On the other hand, there are frameworks like [Arquillian](http://arquillian.org/), that do the thing for you. It supports annotations like @EJB in tests and does DI, manages container.... Read the guide on their website, its worth it.

From my experience, mocks are a no good solution for complex ejb testing, even though it may work on testing some non-container dependant functionality.

My advice is going on it with arquillian.

Comment: That's a good idea. I've heard about Arquillian, but didn't know that it can be used for EJB testing. Thanks

Comment: Gosh yes it can Test EJBs - http://arquillian.org/guides/getting_started_rinse_and_repeat/

Answer (score 2):

I would try to use plain junit and mockito as much as possible to test small units of code and use embedded containers only for integration tests as these kind of tests are running much longer as simple unit tests. And for developers running the unit tests should never get annoying.

Answer (score 1):

An embedded EJB Container used in junit tests is a good idea to integration test your servies & ejbs.

Using open-ejb (or any other embedded container like glassfish etc.) helps you to simple write small tests using junit as framework. Even JPA is integrated very well, using a memory database.

If it comes to mocking, let's say for remote services, you may still use mockito inside.

Find some documented & runnable examples here: https://tomee.apache.org/examples-trunk/

Comment: A link to specific examples for testing would be better than a list of examples for every single thing TomEE is capable of.